# How do I implement __getattribute__ without an infinite recursion error?

Tags: python, class, getattr

I want to override access to one variable in a class, but return all others normally.  How do I accomplish this with `__getattribute__`?

I tried the following (which should also illustrate what I'm trying to do) but I get a recursion error:

```
class D(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.test=20
        self.test2=21
    def __getattribute__(self,name):
        if name=='test':
            return 0.
        else:
            return self.__dict__[name]

>>> print D().test
0.0
>>> print D().test2
...
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp
```

Answer (score 161, accepted):

You get a recursion error because your attempt to access the `self.__dict__` attribute inside `__getattribute__` invokes your `__getattribute__` again. If you use `object`'s `__getattribute__` instead, it works:

```
class D(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.test=20
        self.test2=21
    def __getattribute__(self,name):
        if name=='test':
            return 0.
        else:
            return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
```

This works because `object` (in this example) is the base class. By calling the base version of `__getattribute__` you avoid the recursive hell you were in before.

Ipython output with code in foo.py:

```
In [1]: from foo import *

In [2]: d = D()

In [3]: d.test
Out[3]: 0.0

In [4]: d.test2
Out[4]: 21
```

**Update:**

There's something in the section titled [*More attribute access for new-style classes*](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#more-attribute-access-for-new-style-classes) in the current documentation, where they recommend doing exactly this to avoid the infinite recursion.

Comment: Interesting. So what are you doing there?  Why would object have my variables?

Comment: ..and do I want to always use object?  What if I inherit from other classes?

Comment: Because it's the parent class. You're talking to the base class's version of __getattribute__() rather than your new shiny (and recursion-addled) __getattribute__()

Comment: Use the class you're inheriting from. Whatever that might be.

Comment: If you look at the first argument to object's function, it is self.
Self is the current instance of your class, the object. You use it in a similar manner when you subclass other classes and you need to call their constructur, __init__

Comment: Ah so I'm only taking the function __getattribute__ from the base class, the values are still coming from my class.  So really you can use any class up the hierarchy?

Comment: Though I guess object will have a known good __getattribute__?

Comment: Yes, each time you create a class and you don't write your own, you use the __getattribute__ supplied by object.

Comment: Egil: That's not an entirely safe way to look at it. If I'm using a class that inherits another class, that inherits another class that inherits object (and I didn't write any of the inherited classes) If one of those overrides __getattribute__ and you call object's version, it might not work as ...

Comment: ... expected. You should always call the next rung up the inheritance ladder (unless you know what you're doing).

Comment: But I see that my comment can be misleading.

Comment: @Oli, @Egil, I don't understand why `pass 2 args to object's __getattr__ like this, object.__getattribute__(self, name)? __getattr__ is not staticmethod right?

Comment: @Alcott: No, `__getattribute__()` is not a staticmethod, which is precisely why, when calling the unbound `object` class's version, it is necessary to pass the instance argument `self` in addition to the attribute `name`.

Comment: isn't it better to use super() and thus use the first __getattribute__ method python finds in your base classes? - `super(D, self).__getattribute__(name)`

Comment: Or you can just use `super().__getattribute__(name)` in Python 3.

Comment: Using `object.__getattribute__(self, name)` is a very bad idea if the super-class of `self` is anything other than `object`

Answer (score 35):

Actually, I believe you want to use the [`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) special method instead.

Quote from the Python docs:

> `__getattr__( self, name)`
>
> Called when an attribute lookup has not found the attribute in the usual places (i.e. it is not an instance attribute nor is it found in the class tree for self). `name` is the attribute name. This method should return the (computed) attribute value or raise an `AttributeError` exception.
> Note that if the attribute is found through the normal mechanism, `__getattr__()` is not called. (This is an intentional asymmetry between `__getattr__()` and `__setattr__()`.) This is done both for efficiency reasons and because otherwise `__setattr__()` would have no way to access other attributes of the instance. Note that at least for instance variables, you can fake total control by not inserting any values in the instance attribute dictionary (but instead inserting them in another object). See the `__getattribute__()` method below for a way to actually get total control in new-style classes.

Note: for this to work, the instance should *not* have a `test` attribute, so the line `self.test=20` should be removed.

Comment: Actually, according to the nature of the OP's code, overriding `__getattr__` for `test` would be useless, since it would always find it "in the usual places".

Answer (score 21):

[Python language reference:](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__)

> In order to avoid infinite recursion
>   in this method, its implementation
>   should always call the base class
>   method with the same name to access
>   any attributes it needs, for example,
>   `object.__getattribute__(self, name)`.

Meaning:

```
def __getattribute__(self,name):
    ...
        return self.__dict__[name]
```

You're calling for an attribute called `__dict__`. Because it's an attribute, `__getattribute__` gets called in search for `__dict__` which calls `__getattribute__` which calls ... yada yada yada

```
return  object.__getattribute__(self, name)
```

Using the base classes `__getattribute__` helps finding the real attribute.

Answer (score 14):

> ### How is the `__getattribute__` method used?

It is called before the normal dotted lookup. If it raises `AttributeError`, then we call `__getattr__`.

Use of this method is rather rare. There are only two definitions in the standard library:

```
$ grep -Erl  "def __getattribute__\(self" cpython/Lib | grep -v "/test/"
cpython/Lib/_threading_local.py
cpython/Lib/importlib/util.py
```

**Best Practice**

The proper way to programmatically control access to a single attribute is with [`property`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property). Class `D` should be written as follows (with the setter and deleter optionally to replicate apparent intended behavior):

```
class D(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.test2=21

    @property
    def test(self):
        return 0.

    @test.setter
    def test(self, value):
        '''dummy function to avoid AttributeError on setting property'''

    @test.deleter
    def test(self):
        '''dummy function to avoid AttributeError on deleting property'''
```

And usage:

```
>>> o = D()
>>> o.test
0.0
>>> o.test = 'foo'
>>> o.test
0.0
>>> del o.test
>>> o.test
0.0
```

A property is a data descriptor, thus it is the first thing looked for in the normal dotted lookup algorithm.

### Options for `__getattribute__`

You several options if you absolutely need to implement lookup for every attribute via [`__getattribute__`](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#more-attribute-access-for-new-style-classes).

- raise `AttributeError`, causing `__getattr__` to be called (if implemented)
- return something from it by

  - using [`super`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super) to call the parent (probably `object`'s) implementation
  - calling `__getattr__`
  - implementing your own dotted lookup algorithm somehow

For example:

```
class NoisyAttributes(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.test=20
        self.test2=21
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        print('getting: ' + name)
        try:
            return super(NoisyAttributes, self).__getattribute__(name)
        except AttributeError:
            print('oh no, AttributeError caught and reraising')
            raise
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        """Called if __getattribute__ raises AttributeError"""
        return 'close but no ' + name    


>>> n = NoisyAttributes()
>>> nfoo = n.foo
getting: foo
oh no, AttributeError caught and reraising
>>> nfoo
'close but no foo'
>>> n.test
getting: test
20
```

### What you originally wanted.

And this example shows how you might do what you originally wanted:

```
class D(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.test=20
        self.test2=21
    def __getattribute__(self,name):
        if name=='test':
            return 0.
        else:
            return super(D, self).__getattribute__(name)
```

And will behave like this:

```
>>> o = D()
>>> o.test = 'foo'
>>> o.test
0.0
>>> del o.test
>>> o.test
0.0
>>> del o.test

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#216>", line 1, in <module>
    del o.test
AttributeError: test
```

### Code review

Your code with comments. You have a dotted lookup on self in `__getattribute__`.
This is why you get a recursion error. You could check if name is `"__dict__"` and use `super` to workaround, but that doesn't cover `__slots__`. I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader.

```
class D(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.test=20
        self.test2=21
    def __getattribute__(self,name):
        if name=='test':
            return 0.
        else:      #   v--- Dotted lookup on self in __getattribute__
            return self.__dict__[name]

>>> print D().test
0.0
>>> print D().test2
...
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp
```

Answer (score 13):

Are you sure you want to use `__getattribute__`?  What are you actually trying to achieve?

The easiest way to do what you ask is:

```
class D(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.test = 20
        self.test2 = 21

    test = 0
```

or:

```
class D(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.test = 20
        self.test2 = 21

    @property
    def test(self):
        return 0
```

Edit:
Note that an instance of `D` would have different values of `test` in each case.  In the first case `d.test` would be 20, in the second it would be 0.  I'll leave it to you to work out why.

Edit2:
Greg pointed out that example 2 will fail because the property is read only and the `__init__` method tried to set it to 20.  A more complete example for that would be:

```
class D(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.test = 20
        self.test2 = 21

    _test = 0

    def get_test(self):
        return self._test

    def set_test(self, value):
        self._test = value

    test = property(get_test, set_test)
```

Obviously, as a class this is almost entirely useless, but it gives you an idea to move on from.

Comment: Oh that doesn't quiet work when you run the class though, no?

  File "Script1.py", line 5, in __init__
    self.test = 20
AttributeError: can't set attribute

Comment: True.  I'll fix that up as a third example.  Well spotted.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a more reliable version:

```
class D(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.test = 20
        self.test2 = 21
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name == 'test':
            return 0.
        else:
            return super(D, self).__getattribute__(name)
```

It calls **__*getattribute*__** method from parent class, eventually falling back to object.**__*getattribute*__** method if other ancestors don't override it.