# How can I ensure that one of my class's methods is always called even if a subclass overrides it?

Tags: python, subclass

For example, I have a

```
class BaseHandler(object):
    def prepare(self):
        self.prepped = 1
```

I do not want everyone that subclasses BaseHandler and also wants to implement prepare to have to remember to call

```
super(SubBaseHandler, self).prepare()
```

Is there a way to ensure the superclass method is run even if the subclass also implements prepare?

Comment: The short answer is that you can't. If it's overriden, the member lookup algorithm is required to return the overriden version. A more robust approach would be a design that doesn't require overriding of such vital parts, though that's not always possible. Alternatively, write your code such that it raises and error or produces obviously wrong results when your version is not called, to aid debugging.

Comment: @delnan: Using metaclasses wouldn't be implementation-dependent (but might well be considered a hack, at least if used for this purpose).

Comment: @Sven: I could have sworn there's a "maybe", specifically because I don't trust myself to enumerate all possibilities. But I revised my comment anyway.

Comment: @Sven I don't think metaclasses will be of any help here.

Comment: @Lucho: Well, I can see where he's going - see if subclasses overrides the method, if so wrap it with a version that calls the base class version first. Not perfect (can be overriden again after class creation, can lead to people calling the base class implementation manually though it's already done for them), but moderately robust.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have solved this problem using a metaclass.

Using a metaclass allows the implementer of the `BaseHandler` to be sure that all subclasses will call the superclasses `prepare()` with no adjustment to any existing code.

The metaclass looks for an implementation of `prepare` on both classes and then overwrites the subclass prepare with one that calls `superclass.prepare` followed by `subclass.prepare`.

```
class MetaHandler(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        instance = type.__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
        super_instance = super(instance, instance)
        if hasattr(super_instance, 'prepare') and hasattr(instance, 'prepare'):
            super_prepare = getattr(super_instance, 'prepare')
            sub_prepare = getattr(instance, 'prepare')
            def new_prepare(self):
                super_prepare(self)
                sub_prepare(self)
            setattr(instance, 'prepare', new_prepare)
        return instance


class BaseHandler(object):
    __metaclass__ = MetaHandler
    def prepare(self):
        print 'BaseHandler.prepare'


class SubHandler(BaseHandler):
    def prepare(self):
        print 'SubHandler.prepare'
```

Using it looks like this:

```
>>> sh = SubHandler()
>>> sh.prepare()
BaseHandler.prepare
SubHandler.prepare
```

Answer (score 4):

Tell your developers to define `prepare_hook` instead of `prepare`, but 
tell the users to call `prepare`:

```
class BaseHandler(object):
    def prepare(self):
        self.prepped = 1
        self.prepare_hook()
    def prepare_hook(self):
        pass

class SubBaseHandler(BaseHandler):
    def prepare_hook(self):
        pass

foo = SubBaseHandler()
foo.prepare()
```

If you want more complex chaining of `prepare` calls from multiple subclasses, then your developers should really use `super` as that's what it was intended for.

Comment: This works fine as long as the hierarchy doesn't get any deeper than one level, but given that it seems to be the best solution.

Comment: If telling users to define a special method is fine, then telling them to simply call the base method when overriding it would be just as fine as well. And you wouldn’t introduce other problems like that.

Comment: Although this works, I should have specified that I wanted people subclassing to be able to use the name prepare instead of prepare_hook. The actual use case is that my BaseHandler is subclassing a tornado RequestHandler. Since developers may be familiar with using the prepare method when writing tornado handlers, I would like them to be able to use the same method name even when they inherit from my BaseHandler class. The metaclass solution fits my use case better.

Answer (score 3):

Just accept that you have to tell people subclassing your class to call the base method when overriding it. Every other solution either requires you to explain them to do something else, or involves some un-pythonic hacks which could be circumvented too.

Python’s object inheritance model was designed to be open, and any try to go another way will just overcomplicate the problem which does not really exist anyway. Just tell everybody using your stuff to either follow your “rules”, or the program will mess up.

Answer (score 2):

One explicit solution without too much magic going on would be to maintain a list of prepare call-backs:

```
class BaseHandler(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.prepare_callbacks = []
    def register_prepare_callback(self, callback):
        self.prepare_callbacks.append(callback)
    def prepare(self):
        # Do BaseHandler preparation
        for callback in self.prepare_callbacks:
            callback()

class MyHandler(BaseHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        BaseHandler.__init__(self)
        self.register_prepare_callback(self._prepare)
    def _prepare(self):
        # whatever
```

Comment: Note that you are already overriding `BaseHandler.__init__` with your subclass, so you end up with a AttributeError…

Comment: @poke: Thanks, fixed. :)  Well, now I have somehow moved the problem to `__init__()`…

Comment: You could instead move the initialization of the list to the class body (i.e. before `__init__`, outside of any method), or you could add an existence test into the register method, which initializes it if necessary.

Comment: @poke: I like both suggestions, especially the first one.  And I like your answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

In general you can try using [`__getattribute__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371753/python-using-getattribute-method) to achive something like this (until the moment someone overwrites this method too), but it is against the Python ideas. There is a reason to be able to access private object members in Python. The reason is mentioned in `import this`