# How to add new attributes to struct_spwd type while preserving its original attributes?

Tags: python

Python has spwd module to interact with shadow password file.

You must be root to use spwd module.

```
>>> import spwd;

>>> a = spwd.getspnam('bin')

>>> type(a)
<class 'spwd.struct_spwd'>

>>> a.__gt__
<method-wrapper '__gt__' of spwd.struct_spwd object at 0x7fd017641b80>
```

Now I want to add a new attribute to object 'a' (or class 'struct_spwd'). How do I do that?

Inheritance does not work.

```
import spwd

class Abc(spwd.struct_spwd):
    pass
```

I got "TypeError: type 'spwd.struct_spwd' is not an acceptable base type".

Adding dynamic attributes to object does not work.

```
import spwd

a = spwd.getspnam('bin')
a.new_attribute = lambda: print('hello world')
```

I got "AttributeError: 'spwd.struct_spwd' object has no attribute 'new_attribute'".

Using delegation could work, though. But I want to preserve its original attributes.

```
import spwd

class Abc(object):
    def __init__(self, struct_spwd):
        self.struct_spwd = struct_spwd

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name=='new_attribute':
            print('hello world')
        else:
            self.struct_spwd.__getattribute__(name)

a = spwd.getspnam('bin')
b = Abc(a)
b.new_attribute
b.__gt__
```

I got "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison".

Any idea? Or should I use other ways to achieve my goal? Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Wrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, wrapped):
        self.wrapped = wrapped

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name.startswith('sp_'):
            value = getattr(self.wrapped, name)
            setattr(self, name, value)
            return value

        raise AttributeError
```

The code also caches the values, so that `__getattr__` is only called once per each member.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't like the filtering and raising exception explicitly though. I prefer to send both of them to the wrapped object.

Comment: I added the filtering, because the shadow object contained other properties too, namely `n_unnamed_fields` and so forth... but you are welcome to remove if needed :D

Answer (score 2):

Check out this thread:

[How is the __getattribute__ method used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371753/python-using-getattribute-method)

What you want to use is getattr():

`class Abc(object):
    def __init__(self, struct_spwd):
        self.struct_spwd = struct_spwd

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name=='new_attribute':
            print('hello world')
        else:
            return getattr(self.struct_spwd, name)`