# Python Inheritance and __getattr__ & __getattribute__

Tags: python-2.7, inheritance, getattr, getattribute

I have fought with this all day long and done plenty of Google searches. I am having what appears to be an inheritance problem.

I have a class named BaseClass that does some simple things for me like set logging defaults, hold the log, and manage Read Only attributes. In the past I have had no issues with this class but I can say I've only been using python for a couple of months now. Additionally, there are a couple of caveats I suspect are important:

1. All past inheritance has been a single inheritance. In other words I have inherited BaseClass but the class that inherits BaseClass is NOT then inherited by another class. In today's problem, I inherit BaseClass into BaseFormData which is then inherited into July2013FormData which is then inherited into Jan2014FormData. So obviously there are more layers now.
2. I have not been attempting to override `__getattr__` or `__getattribute__` in any of the classes that inherited BaseClass in the past. Today I am. BaseClass has a `__getattribute__` method of its own in order to manage the getting of Read Only attributes. The BaseFormData class has a `__getattr__` method because I'd read this was the right way to provide access to data without having to explicitly declare all attributes. The form data being loaded up has a dozen or more pieces of data in it (depending on the version) so I'm explicitly declaring some properties that are vital or aliased while leaving the rest to handled by `__getattr__`.

Here is the `__getattribute__` from BaseClass:

```
def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        try:
            # Default behaviour
            return object.__getattribute__(self, attr)
        except:
            try:
                return self.__READ_ONLY[attr]
            except KeyError:
                lcAttr = php_basic_str.strtolower(attr)
                return self._raw[lcAttr]
```

The lines that use `self._raw` are there solely because classes that inherit BaseClass often times use `_raw`. There is no `_raw` that BaseClass requires. Ideally the reference to `_raw` would only appear in the `__getattr__` or `__getattribute__` of the inheriting class. However, I need to use `__getattribute__` in BaseClass in order to get the Read Only functionality working properly.

And the `__getattr__` from BaseFormData:

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
        """
        Return a particular piece of data from the _raw dict
        """

        # All the columns are saved in lowercase
        lcName = s.strtolower(name)

        try:
            tmp = self._raw[lcName]
        except KeyError:
            try:
                tmp = super(BaseFormData, self).__getattribute__(name)
            except KeyError:
                msg = "'{0}' object has no attribute '{1}'. Note that attribute search is case insensitive."
                raise AttributeError(msg.format(type(self).__name__, name))

        if tmp == 'true':
            return True
        elif tmp == 'false':
            return False
        else:
            return tmp
```

Here is the error I'm receiving:

```
File "D:\python\lib\mybasics\mybasics\cBaseClass.py", line 195, in __getattribute__
    return self.__READ_ONLY[attr]

RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

The short version is that I have fought all day with this because with a tweak here or there I get differing response. Most of the time `__getattr__` from BaseFormData is never called. Other times I get this recursion error. Other time I can get it to work but then I add something small and everything breaks again.

There is something that I'm clearly missing with regards to inheritance and the order in which `__getattribute__` and `__getattr__` are called. I've done a lot of tweaking of the code today and if memory serves I can't have a `__getattribute__` in BaseFormData as well as BaseClass but I don't remember the error off the top of my head.

I'm guessing the recursion issue stems from this line in `__getattr__`:

```
tmp = super(BaseFormData, self).__getattribute__(name)
```

Obviously, what I'm wanting to do is look in the current class first, then go to the BaseClass `__getattribute__` in order to check for Read Only attributes.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

----------- Results of a few tweaks.... -----------

So I changed BaseFormClass `__getattr__` to `__getattribute__` and it seemed to run before BaseClass's `__getattribute__` which makes sense.

However it led to infinite recursion which I thought might be due to the order certain things happened in the `__init__` of BaseFormClass and children classes of BaseFormClass. Then it seemed to be due to __READ_ONLY being created too late and I fixed that as well.

Ultimately, `_raw` is in the children class not in BaseClass so I removed any reference to `_raw` in BaseClass's `_getattribute__`. I took rchang's suggestion about changing self to object and this helped in BaseClass's `__getattribute__` but seemed to cause issues in BaseFormData's. I have gotten the "get" portion to work from the interpreter with the code below:

BaseClass:

```
def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        try:
            # Default behaviour
            return object.__getattribute__(self, attr)
        except:
            return self.__READ_ONLY[attr]
```

BaseFormClass:

```
def __getattribute__(self, name):
        # All the columns are saved in lowercase
        lcName = s.strtolower(name)

        try:
            # Default behaviour
            return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
        except:
            try:
                tmp = object.__getattribute__(self, '_raw')[lcName]
            except KeyError:
                try:
                    tmp = BaseClass.__getattribute__(self, name)
                except KeyError:
                    msg = "'{0}' object has no attribute '{1}'. Note that attribute search is case insensitive."
                    raise AttributeError(msg.format(type(self).__name__, name))

            if tmp == 'true':
                return True
            elif tmp == 'false':
                return False
            else:
                return tmp
```

Ironically this has created another `__getattribute__` issue though. When I attempt to overwrite a Read Only attr the log warning fires but then fails on a call to `self.__instanceId`. This log warning worked fine yesterday (when I could get the classes to instantiate without error). And I can instantiate the class like this:

```
a = Jan2014Lead(leadFile)
```

and get the Instance ID like this:

```
a.__instanceId
Out[7]: '8c08dee80ef56b1234fc4822627febfc'
```

Here's the actual error:

```
File "D:\python\lib\mybasics\mybasics\cBaseClass.py", line 255, in write2log
    logStr = "[" + self.__instanceId + "]::[" + str(msgCode) + "]::" + msgMsg

  File "cBaseFormData.py", line 226, in __getattribute__
    raise AttributeError(msg.format(type(self).__name__, name))

AttributeError: 'Jan2014Lead' object has no attribute '_BaseClass__instanceId'. Note that attribute search is case insensitive.
```

----------- Got it working but seems hacky.... -----------

So the error above is from looking for _BaseClass__instanceId in _READ_ONLY but __instanceId is in _READ_ONLY. So I simply trimmed the attr string passed to remove _BaseClass from the beginning.

This seems like a hack though. Is there a standard way to do this?

Comment: It's not clear to me what exactly your `__READ_ONLY` dictionary is for. As you've currently implemented `__getattribute__`, it's only going to be checked once ordinary lookups have failed, which means that (unless you have a `__setattr__` method you haven't mentioned), regular instance variables can sill be assigned and they'll take precedence over the dictionary's values. Perhaps you should leave `__getattribute__` alone and write a `__setattr__` method that raises an exception for certain names instead?

Comment: @Blckknght I already have a `__setattr__` that raises an exception when an attempt to overwrite a Read Only attr is made. I just didn't think it was relevant to this issue. I wrote the BaseClass in the first week or so I was learning python and the combo of `__getattribute__` and `__setattr__` was the only way I could get it to work the way I expected. I may need to revisit it but for now the `__setattr__` isn't a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say I ever fully figured this out to my satisfaction. However, the BaseClass `__getattirbute__` method required a change in the order in which things were being called:

```
def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        if attr in self.__READ_ONLY:
            return self.__READ_ONLY[attr]
        else:
            # Default behaviour
            return object.__getattribute__(self, attr)
```

Then I needed another change to the `__getattribute__` in BaseFormClass:

```
def __getattribute__(self, name):
        # All the columns are saved in lowercase
        lcName = s.strtolower(name)

        try:
            # Default behaviour
            return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
        except:
            name = s.str_replace('_' + type(self).__name__, '', name)
            lcName = s.strtolower(name)

            try:
                tmp = object.__getattribute__(self, '_raw')[lcName]
            except KeyError:
                #tmp = BaseClass.__getattribute__(self, name)
                tmp = super(BaseFormData, self).__getattribute__(name)

            if tmp == 'true':
                return True
            elif tmp == 'false':
                return False
            else:
                return tmp
```

There are really just 2 changes here. The easy one first, I removed the raise and let the BaseClass handle that. The harder to describe change is the one where I strip out the class name using `s.str_replace`. Without this line Python was often looking for something like `_BaseClass__{some attr}` in the `_READ_ONLY` dict. However, it was only named `{some attr}` within the `_READ_ONLY` dict. So I strip the `_BaseClass_` portion out.

Obviously this is a hack. I'm not sure if implementing some form of aliasing wouldn't be better than stripping it out. Possibly more explicit? Either way it seems like a hack to get around Python's built-in method for keeping attributes unique among classes.

I imagine there is a better way to do this and this will likely get completely rewritten in a year or so to reflect that better way.

Answer (score 1):

I think your're hitting infinite recursions because `__getattribute__` is trying to directly look up attributes of self and therefore results in `__getattribute__` calling itself in those except blocks.  See this SO question:
[How is the __getattribute__ method used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371753/python-using-getattribute-method)

Maybe try the following (just extend the same technique using `object.__getattribute__` that you're using in the try block to the except block too)?

```
def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        try:
            # Default behaviour
            return object.__getattribute__(self, attr)
        except:
            try:
                # return self.__READ_ONLY[attr]
                return object.__getattribute__(self, __READ_ONLY)[attr]
            except KeyError:
                lcAttr = php_basic_str.strtolower(attr)
                # return self._raw[lcAttr]
                return object.__getattribute__(self, _raw)[lcAttr]
```

Comment: I tried a simplified version where the whole 2nd try except block for just becomes the return __READ_ONLY line. Still getting infinite recursion. My real issue here seems to me to be one where BaseClass's `__getattribute__` is being called prior to BaseFormData's `__getattr__` or `__getattribute__`. I'm missing something...