# maximum recursion depth exceeded getter Django

Tags: python, django, recursion, django-models, attributes

I have some class with custom getter for specific attr:

```
class Item(a, b, c, d, models.Model):
     title = Field()
     description = Field()
     a = Field()
     _custom_getter = ['title','description']

     def __getattribute__(self, name):
         if name in self.custom_getter:
             return 'xxx'
         else:
             return super(Item, self).__getattribute__(name)
```

this code raise `RunetimeError`: `maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`
but when i use this piece of code:

```
class Item(a, b, c, d, models.Model):
    title = Field()
    description = Field()
    a = Field()

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        custom_getter = ['title','description']
        if name in custom_getter:
            return 'xxx'
        else:
            return super(Item, self).__getattribute__(name)
```

all works like I want. Wher is my mistake in first piece of code ?

Answer (score 3):

Because `__getattribute__` gets called when you do `self.custom_getter`. You can use `self.__dict__` for this. Read more [How is the __getattribute__ method used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371753/python-using-getattribute-method#371833)

```
class Item(a, b, c, d, models.Model):
     title = Field()
     description = Field()
     a = Field()
     custom_getter = ['title','description']

     def __getattribute__(self, name):
         if name in self.__dict__['custom_getter']:
             return 'xxx'
         else:
             return super(Item, self).__getattribute__(name)
```

Comment: I use `object.__getattribute__(self, '_custom_getter')` instead `self.__dict__['_custom_getter']` because it generate same error, but thanks for article, I found solution ther.