# How does object.__getattribute__ redirect to __get__ method on my descriptor and __getattr__?

Tags: python, oop

I have a two-part question regarding the implementation of `object.__getattribute(self, key)`, but they are both centered around my confusion of how it is working.

I've defined a data descriptor called `NonNullStringDescriptor` that I intended to attach to attributes.

```
class NonNullStringDescriptor:

    def __init__(self, value: str = "Default Name"):
        self.value = value

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return self.value

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if isinstance(value, str) and len(value.strip()) > 0:
            self.value = value
        else:
            raise TypeError("The value provided is not a non-null string.")
```

I then declare a `Person` class with an attribute of `name`.

```py
class Person:
    name = NonNullStringDescriptor()

    def __init__(self):
        self.age = 22

    def __getattribute__(self, key):
        print(f"__getattribute__({key})")
        v = super(Person, self).__getattribute__(key)
        print(f"Returned {v}")

        if hasattr(v, '__get__'):
            print("Invoking __get__")
            return v.__get__(None, self)
        return v

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        print(f"__getattr__ invoked.")
        return "Unknown"
```

Now, I try accessing variable attributes, some that are descriptors, some normal instance attributes, and others that don't exist:

```
    person = Person()
    print("Printing", person.age) # "normal" attribute
    print("Printing", person.hobby) # non-existent attribute
    print("Printing", person.name) # descriptor attribute
```

The output that is see is

```
__getattribute__(age)
Returned 22
Printing 22
__getattribute__(hobby)
__getattr__ invoked.
Printing Unknown
__getattribute__(name)
Returned Default Name
Printing Default Name
```

I have two main questions, both of which center around `super(Person, self).__getattribute__(key)`:

1. When I attempt to access a non-existent attribute, like `hobby`, I see that it redirects to `__getattr__`, which I know is often the "fallback" method in attribute lookup. However, I see that `__getattribute__` is what is invoking this method. However, the `Returned ...` console output is never printed meaning that the rest of the `__getattribute__` does not complete - so how exactly is `__getattribute__` invoking `__getattr__` directly, returning this default "Unknown" value without executing the rest of its own function call?
2. I would expect that what is returned from `super(Person, self).__getattribute__(key)` (`v`), is the data descriptor instance of `NonNullStringDescriptor`. However, I see that `v` is actually the string "Default Name" itself! So how does `object.__getattribute__(self, key)` just know to use the `__get__` method of my descriptor, instead of returning the descriptor instance?

There's references to behavior in the [Descriptor Protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html):

> If the looked-up value is an object defining one of the descriptor
>   methods, then **Python may override the default behavior and invoke the
>   descriptor method** instead.

But it's never explicitly defined to me what is actually happening in `object.__getattribute(self, key)` that performs the override. I know that ultimately `person.name` gets converted into a low-level call to `type(person).__dict__["name"].__get__(person, type(person))`- is this all happening in `object.__getattribute__`?

I found this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371753/how-do-i-implement-getattribute-without-an-infinite-recursion-error), which describes proper implementation of `__getattribute__`, but I'm more curious at what is actually happening in `object.__getattribute__`. However, my IDE (PyCharm) only provides a stub for its implementation:

```
def __getattribute__(self, *args, **kwargs): # real signature unknown
        """ Return getattr(self, name). """
        pass
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`__getattribute__` doesn't call `__getattr__`. The `__getattr__` fallback happens in the attribute access machinery, *after* `__getattribute__` raises an `AttributeError`. If you want to see the implementation, it's in [`slot_tp_getattr_hook`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.2/Objects/typeobject.c#L6567) in `Objects/typeobject.c`.

`object.__getattribute__` knows to call `__get__` because there's code in `object.__getattribute__` that calls `__get__`. It's pretty straightforward. If you want to see the implementation, `object.__getattribute__` is [`PyObject_GenericGetAttr`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.2/Objects/object.c#L1332) in the implementation (yes, even though it says GetAttr - the C side of things is a little different from the Python side), and there are two `__get__` call sites (one for data descriptors and one for non-data descriptors), [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.2/Objects/object.c#L1249-L1261) and [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.2/Objects/object.c#L1306-L1313).

Comment: Great, thank you for this. I guess this is more or less saying that this is the furthest I'll be able to get without diving deeper into the C-level built-in source implementation code?

Comment: Ah! I see it now! This is so cool. I see the call to the getter function on this line here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7b3ab5921fa25ed8b97b6296f97c5c78aacf5447/Objects/object.c#L1254