# From python how to split a list where ever a ":" in line

Tags: python, list

```
    import docker
    import sys
    client= docker.from_env()
    app_name=sys.argv[1]
    def docker():
          tag=[]
          newList=[]
          #image=[]
          for container in client.containers.list(filters={"name":app_name}):
    
              a=container.image
              tag.append(a)
          print(tag[0])
         # for i in tag:
          #      newList.append(i.split(':')[0])
    
          #rint(newList)
    docker()
```

''
I'm getting output like this "<Image: 'gcr.io/ec2nf-256816/upf-fpm:it.r2.4.6'>"
Could you please help me to get only "it.r2.4.6".
''

Comment: string.split(':')[-1].split("'")[0] but replace string with the string you provided.

Comment: but my  output is stored in list and it is not as string

Comment: but split only works for string

Comment: print(a.split(':'))
AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'split'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
s = tag[0].__str__()
print(s)
print(s.split(':')[-1].split("'")[0])
```

```
Out: "<Image: 'gcr.io/ec2nf-256816/upf-fpm:it.r2.4.6'>"
Out: "it.r2.4.6"
```

#### What happens here?

`s = tag[0].__str__()` gets the Image tag as a string.

Then `s.split(':')` happens first which gives us:

```
['<Image', " 'gcr.io/ec2nf-256816/upf-fpm", "it.r2.4.6'>"]
```

Then we take the last element [-1] and split it by "'"

```
['it.r2.4.6', '>']
```

Then we just need to take the 0<sup>th</sup> element, since that's the target result.

```
"it.r2.4.6"
```

Comment: The above is not working on my case. Please help me

Comment: Can you share the output for `dir(tag[0])`.  We might be able to access the Image element of it.

Comment: print(tag[0])
output:
<Image: 'gcr.io/ec2nf-256816/upf-fpm:it.r2.4.6'>

Comment: Our goal here is just to find a way to access this string 'gcr.io/ec2nf-256816/upf-fpm:it.r2.4.6' within the tag, then parsing should be very simple.  Does `print(tag[0].Image)` give you that string or perhaps `tag[0]["Image"]`?

Comment: print(tag[0].Image )-->not getting expected result

Comment: print(tag[0]["Image"])
TypeError: 'Image' object is not subscriptable

Comment: If you print `type(tag[0])` we might be able to do a more directed search to figure out how to access the item.  They certainly don't make it easy.

Comment: print(type(tag[0]))--><class 'docker.models.images.Image'>

Comment: it should have a list of accessible parameters which you can view if you `print(dir(tag[0]))`.  One of those parameters should contain the "Image" info.

Comment: print(dir(tag[0])):
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'attrs', 'client', 'collection', 'history', 'id', 'id_attribute', 'labels', 'reload', 'save', 'short_id', 'tag', 'tags']
<class 'docker.models.images.Image'>

Comment: tag[0].getattribute('Image') sounds like what we're looking for.

Comment: this one is not working print(tag[0].getattribute('Image'))
but print(tag[0].tag)
O/P: <bound method Image.tag of <Image: 'gcr.io/ec2nf-256816/upf-fpm:it.r2.4.6'>>

But i'm not getting how to get only "it.r2.4.6"..?

Comment: My final out put is this  when  I use  print(tag[0].tags)
 python3 py.py  upf-fpm
['gcr.io/ec2nf-256816/upf-fpm:it.r2.4.6']

Comment: Is that a list with a string in it that you can access?

Comment: No, I could not able to access the string

Comment: It definitely feels like we're getting closer.  I have to get some rest though, I'll comment if I have any ideas later.  One last thought, try `help(tag[0].getattribute)` just to read what argument it is asking for.  It seems like this should be the key to accessing the  target string.  Perhaps even just `tag[0].getattribute()` with no argument might work since there is only one item.

Comment: Sure ,I will try above solution   and please let me know if you have any ideas. Thank you so much Mr LPR.

Comment: print(tag[0].getattribute())

AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'getattribute'

Comment: Not sure why I didn't realize this last night, but the bold items in the list `dir(tag[0])` are bold because of the formatting here.  So `getattribute` is actually `__getattribute__`.  That said, here is how `__getattribute__` works: https://medium.com/@satishgoda/python-attribute-access-using-getattr-and-getattribute-6401f7425ce6 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371753/how-do-i-implement-getattribute-without-an-infinite-recursion-error/371833#371833 so if `__getattribute__` was going to work, then tag[0].Image should have worked.

Comment: That said, you might try `tag[0].__str__()` or `tag[0].__repr__()` or `tag[0].__dict__['Image']`

Comment: im getting output is this : <Image: 'gcr.io/ec2nf-256816/upf-fpm:it.r2.4.6'>
but how get only "it.r2.4.6" from the above output.

Comment: Is that the output from `tag[0].__str__()` and is it a string i.e. is `type(tag[0].__str__())` is a string?  If so then `s = tag[0].__str__()` followed by the initial solution shown in the answer should work.  Although, if it is still not a string, then I am stumped.

Comment: Awesome Thank you so much Mr. LPR . I have use  s = tag[0].__str__() and its type is string.
Then I use  a=s.split(':')[-1].split("'")[0])

Comment: Great! So glad to hear `tag[0].__str__().split(':')[-1].split("'")[0]` works!  I'll update the answer so anyone who comes across this with a similar problem doesn't need to read our entire conversation XD