# Prevent (or work with) altering class attribute accessed from getter, bypassing setter, in Python

Tags: python, object, oop

I'm trying to create a Python class, and one of the attributes is a dictionary of dictionaries. I construct it using getters and setters because there are certain checks that need to be done to ensure that data types are correct, etc. The intended use is to use a function to add the entries so that it can go through the checks, but what I discovered is that you can directly access the dictionary attribute and add a key to it, thereby bypassing the built-in checks of the function.

My question is:

1. Is there a way to prevent the behavior of `Object.dict_attribute[key] = some_dictionary` that bypasses the checks and the intended `Object.add_item(some_dictionary)` function?
2. If not, is there a way to trigger the `Object.add_item(some_dictionary)` function when `Object.dict_attribute[key] = some_dictionary` is called, possibly using magic methods?

Below is a toy example I made that should reproduce the behavior that I described. This was run and tested with Python 3.10.2.

```
# Bookcase can hold books, but the total needs to be 
# under a certain weight per shelf. 
class Bookcase:
    def __init__(self, num_shelves: int = 1, 
                 weight_limit: float = 50.0, books: dict = None) -> 'Bookcase': 
        # Create our shelves. 
        self.shelves = num_shelves
        self.weight_limit = weight_limit

        # Add the books if they are defined. 
        if books is not None:
            self.books = books

    ### PRIVATE FUNCTIONS ###
    # Check that a book is well-defined. 
    def _check_book(book: dict) -> bool: 
        return((type(book) == dict and
                len(set(book.keys()).intersection(set(["weight", "shelf"]))) == 2))
    
    # If a book is good, try adding to shelf. 
    def _add_book_to_shelf(self, book: dict) -> None: 
        
        # Check defined keys. 
        if not Bookcase._check_book(book):
            raise Exception("Each book should have a target shelf and a weight.")

        target = book['shelf']

        # If good, add it to the shelf, making sure that we do not exceed the weight. 
        if self._shelves[target]['weight'] + book['weight'] <= self.weight_limit:
            self._shelves[target]['weight'] += book['weight']
            self._shelves[target]['books'].append(book)
        else:
            raise Exception(f"Cannot add book to shelf {target}, doing so will exceed weight.")

        return()

    ### PROPERTIES ###
    @property
    def shelves(self) -> dict:
        return(self._shelves)
    
    # Initialize empty shelves. These shelves will contain book keys and a total weight. 
    @shelves.setter
    def shelves(self, num_shelves: int) -> None: 
        self._shelves = {}
        if type(num_shelves) != int:
            raise Exception("Shelves needs to be an integer.")
        for i in range(num_shelves):
            self._shelves[i] = {"books": [], "weight": 0}
        return()
    
    @property
    def weight_limit(self) -> dict:
        return(self._limit)
    
    @weight_limit.setter
    def weight_limit(self, limit: int) -> None: 
        self._limit = limit
        return()

    @property 
    def books(self) -> dict:
        ret_list: list = []
        for key in self._shelves:
            ret_list += self._shelves
        return(ret_list)
    
    # Books is a list of dictionaries with keys "name", "shelf", "weight".
    @books.setter
    def books(self, books: list[dict]) -> None: 
        # Empty our shelves and get rid of pre-existing books. 
        self.shelves = len(self.shelves.keys())

        # Each book should contain a name (key), a target shelf, and a weight. 
        for book in books:
            self._add_book_to_shelf(book)

        return()

    ##### NOTE ERROR HERE #####
    # The user should use this function to add a book to the shelf. 
    # We need to go through this function so that the checks are done. 
    def add_book(self, book: dict) -> None: 
        self._add_book_to_shelf(book)
        return()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    # Initialize a list of books. 
    books = [
        {'name': 'Hungry Caterpiller', 'shelf': 0, 'weight': 0.5}, 
        {'name': 'To Kill a Mockingbird', 'shelf': 0, 'weight': 1.0},
        {'name': '1984', 'shelf': 1, 'weight': 1.0}
    ]

    # Make our bookcase with our starting books. 
    library = Bookcase(num_shelves = 2, weight_limit = 20, books = books)

    # Let's define a big book. 
    big_book = {'name': 'Complete Tolkien Works', 'shelf': 1, 'weight': 200}
    
    # Add another book. This should fail. 
    ###
    ### UNCOMMENT FOR ERROR
    ###
    #library.add_book(big_book) # -> Results in appropriate error. 

    # Let's bypass that silly function, because why not? 
    library.shelves[1]['books'].append(big_book)

    # Let's check our shelves now. 
    for shelf in library.shelves.keys():
        print(shelf, library.shelves[shelf])

    # It worked, but we don't want it to!
```

### Here is another way to look at the problem.

```
# This calls the getter, which returns the attribute.
#           |   This gets the 'book' key of the returned value. 
#           |         |    Why does this, then, save it in memory
#           |         |    if it was accessed by a getter?
#           |         |        |
#           V         V        V
library.shelves[1]['books'].append(big_book)
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371753/how-do-i-implement-getattribute-without-an-infinite-recursion-error) help at all?

Comment: I don't really think so, the answers and question seem to be about accessing a user-defined class, but my problem is about the direct access of a base Python class that is used as an attribute in my custom class. What might be worth a try is to create a subclass of `dict` where I can directly control what is (and isn't) added to it, and use that class as my attributes, but that could also be quite a bit of work if there is already another solution available that I'm not understanding.

Comment: I see your update. The `.shelves` attribute is a getter as you say: It is accessed via the `@property def shelves(self):`. This returns a reference to a `dict` which knows nothing of your `property/setter` arrangement. (The `[1]['books']` goes on to yield a `list`, which, again, knows nothing, except that `.append()` is quite valid)

Comment: So my attribute `shelves` is essentially pointing to an memory address. My getter is returning that memory address, and my `.append` is altering the object at that address. Makes sense! In that case, I can see why this is happening. Maybe returning a copy using the getter would be a better solution? I'll have to tinker around with it!

Comment: @JoshuaMincer it's *referring to an object*. Stop thinking about memory addresses. That is the wrong level of abstraction. Your getter returns an object. Then that object can get mutated.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, going to brush up on the abstraction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Technical Note**

---

Before anything else a technical recommendation: If you're really worried about others (developers) accessing attributes or methods that **should not** be public accessible I would strongly recommend change from Python to other language like: Go, Rust, Java, etc. You will have a much better time enforcing public and private policies.

**Issue**

---

Code is allowing anyone to by-pass constraint check routines.

**Suggestion**

---

The simplest suggestion here is to build an specialized `list` to hold books.

First step is to inherit the base `list`:

```py
class BookList(list):
```

Second step is to provide a way to `BookList` to know what's the maximum weight
of a shelve:

```py
class BookList(list):
    def __init__(self, weight_limit):
        self.shelve = weight_limit
        super().__init__()
```

Third step is to make sure we cannot append more than we (shelve) handles:

```py
class BookList(list):
    def __init__(self, weight_limit):
        self.weight_limit = weight_limit
        super().__init__()
    def append(self, book):
        # Recover the current list of book
        curr_weight = sum([b['weight'] for b in self])
        new_weight = curr_weight + book['weight']
        if new_weight > self.weight_limit:
            raise Exception("book weight pass the max weight limit")
        super().append(book)
```

We can run some tests:

```py
max_weight = 5
books = BookList(max_weight)
books.append({'weight': 3})
books.append({'weight': 2})
books.append({'weight': 1})  # raises exception
```

If might wanna look at this [really good example](https://realpython.com/inherit-python-list/) on what other methods you would want to override when
inheriting `list`

**Personal Take**

---

As far as I can understand the **weight limit** is only tied to the Bookcase
which makes the shelves pretty much useless on that perspective. If that's
correct I would probably drop the shelves layers.

If that's not the case then I would presume each shelve is supposed to have
their own weight limit definition.

Let's say we have a single Shelve has a limit of 5 units of weight. If a
Bookcase is composed of 10 Shelves the max weight limit would be 50 units of
weight. On this scenario it makes a lot more sense abstracting Shelves:

```py
class ShelfCannotHoldBook(Exception):
    def __init__(self, book, *args: object) -> None:
        self.book = book
        super().__init__(*args)

class AllBookcaseShelvesAreFull(Exception):
    pass


class Book(object):
    def __init__(self, weight):
        self.weight = weight

class Shelf(list):
    def __init__(self, bookcase, max_weight):
        self.bookcase = bookcase
        self.max_weight = max_weight
        super().__init__()

    def append(self, new_book):
        curr_shelf_weight = sum([b.weight for b in self])
        new_shelf_weight = curr_shelf_weight + new_book.weight
        if new_shelf_weight > self.max_weight:
            raise ShelfCannotHoldBook(new_book)
        super().append(new_book)

class Bookcase():
    def __init__ (self, shelves, shelf_weight):
        """
        Params:
            shelves (int) - how many shelves we want
            shelf_weight (int) - maximum weight for a single shelf
        """
        self.max_weight = shelves * shelf_weight
        self.shelves = [Shelf(self, shelf_weight) for _ in range(shelves)]
    
    def add_book(self, new_book):
        for shelf in self.shelves:
            try:
                shelf.append(new_book)
                return
            except ShelfCannotHoldBook as ex:
                # we want to try other shelves
                continue
        raise AllBookcaseShelvesAreFull
```

You can run some tests:

```py
# Executing happy path
case = Bookcase(2, 2)  # Two shelves each able to hold 2 weight units
case.add_book(Book(1))
case.add_book(Book(1))
case.add_book(Book(2))
try:
    case.add_book(Book(1))
except Exception as ex:
    assert isinstance(ex, AllBookcaseShelvesAreFull)

# Trying to by-pass
case = Bookcase(2, 2)  # Two shelves each able to hold 2 weight units
case.shelves[0].append(Book(1))
case.shelves[0].append(Book(1))
try:
    case.shelves[0].append(Book(1))
except Exception as ex:
    assert isinstance(ex, ShelfCannotHoldBook)

case.shelves[1].append(Book(2))
try:
    case.shelves[1].append(Book(2))
except Exception as ex:
    assert isinstance(ex, ShelfCannotHoldBook)
```

Comment: While the Bookcase class was only meant to frame the question with a toy example, the extensive answer that you provided (as well as recommendations from others) certainly helps with understanding different class-based implementations and solutions for working within the limits of Python class properties, especially as it relates to redefining base Python class functions. I appreciate the thorough help and marking it as solved!

Comment: Additionally, with the original prompt of specifically using a dictionary property, it seems that creating a subclass of dictionary and redefining the behavior of __setitem__, as you had done above with .append, is what would I would need. Thanks again!  https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setitem__

Answer (score 0):

**edit** I hope a better answer.

When you assigned the dictionary inside you object instance, you don't copy the object, and you don't block any modification of your object. Python attributes to each object an id which can be found with the [`id` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id).

Here a toy object with a class and some modification

```py
class WithoutCopy:
    def __init__(self):
        self._inside_object_dict = {}

    @property
    def inside_dict(self):
        return self._inside_object_dict

    @inside_dict.setter
    def inside_dict(self, new_dict):
        self._inside_object_dict = new_dict

if __name__ == '__main__':

    my_dict = {"a": 1}

    without_copy = WithoutCopy()
    without_copy.inside_dict = my_dict
    print(f"dict in object have the same id: {id(without_copy.inside_dict) == id(my_dict)}, {id(my_dict)}")
    my_dict.update({"b": 2})
    print(f"{my_dict=} is the same as {without_copy.inside_dict=}")
```

It will print something like this (ids will be different):

```
dict in object have the same id: True, 140369573356096
my_dict={'a': 1, 'b': {'c': 2}, 'd': 4} is the same as without_copy.inside_dict={'a': 1, 'b': {'c': 2}, 'd': 4}
```

If you want to isolate modifications done on your dictionary, you can [copy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#module-copy) it when assigning it with the setter.

```py
class DictCopy:
    def __init__(self):
        self.inside_object_dict = {}

    @property
    def inside_dict(self):
        return copy(self.inside_object_dict)

    @inside_dict.setter
    def inside_dict(self, new_dict):
        self.inside_object_dict = copy(new_dict)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    inner_dict = {"c": 2}
    my_dict = {"a": 1, "b": inner_dict}

    object_with_copy = DictCopy()
    print(f"inner_dict id: {id(inner_dict)}")
    print(f"my_dict id: {id(my_dict)}")
    object_with_copy.inside_dict = my_dict
    print(f"copied dict inside object: {id(object_with_copy.inside_dict)}")
    print(f"not copied inner dict inside object: {id(object_with_copy.inside_dict["b"])}")

    # With the copy, you can modify the first dictionary without changing the
    # one in the object
    my_dict.update({"d": 10})
    print(f"{my_dict=}")
    print(f"{object_with_copy.inside_dict=}")

    # But, the inner dictionary is still linked to the same object, there
    # wasn't any copy of it so modifying it, will modify the inner dictionary
    # of the object
    inner_dict.update({"e": 11})
    print(f"{my_dict=}")
    print(f"{object_with_copy.inside_dict=}")
```

If you want a full copy of the dictionary, you'll need to use the deepcopy function.

```py
class DictDeepCopy:
    def __init__(self):
        self.inside_object_dict = {}

    @property
    def inside_dict(self):
        return deepcopy(self.inside_object_dict)

    @inside_dict.setter
    def inside_dict(self, new_dict):
        self.inside_object_dict = deepcopy(new_dict)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    inner_dict = {"c": 2}
    my_dict = {"a": 1, "b": inner_dict}

    object_with_deepcopy = DictDeepCopy()
    object_with_deepcopy.inside_dict = my_dict
    inner_dict.update({"f": 12})
    print(f"{my_dict=}")
    print(f"{object_with_deepcopy.inside_dict=}")
```

---

**first answer**

In Python, lots of things are only convention. Users know that by convention, they shouldn't modify directly an attribute.

Usually, an "private" attribute should start with a `_` thus `_shelves` instead of `shelves`.

If you really want to do something closer to more oriented object language you can use a `__` prefixed object like in the following example:

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, a: int):
        self.__a = a

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self.__a

    @a.setter
    def a(self, new_a):
        if new_a > 10:
            self.__a = new_a / 2
        else:
            self.__a = new_a


if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_object = MyClass(3)
    my_object.a = 12
    print(dir(my_object))
    print(my_object.a)
    # the following line will create a new attribute
    my_object.__a = 14
    print(dir(my_object))
    print(my_object.__a)
```

`dir` function prints attribute linked to Python object and you'll see that the second one will add a `__a` attribute added to the `_MyClass__a` one which is the `self.__a` attribute created in the `__init__` function.

---

You shouldn't put the target shelves in the dictionary because it's not linked to the book but to `Bookcase` behavior.

```py
    def add_book(self, book: dict, shelf_target: int) -> None: 
        self._add_book_to_shelf(book, shelf_target)
```

If you want to attribute automatically the book to the lightest shelf, the `shelves` in the dictionary will be useless and weird.

Comment: This definitely isn't the most sensible code, just a quick thing to illustrate the behavior. This is as far as `Bookcase` will go! 

However, I see what you're saying; if you only use the private attribute in the class methods, which the setter sets. That's what I'm trying above, but my main confusion is how the getter is reacting with the class; accessing the `shelves` dictionary through the getter and altering it's `books` then saves those changes in the shelf's memory. What confuses me is how the dictionary, accessed by the getter, is modified and still saved in the object's memory

Comment: why would a double-underscore be more object oriented? And why would you use it here instead of a single underscore?

Comment: @JoshuaMincer what exactly isn't you don't understand? The `Bookcase` instance references a `dict` instance. That dict is returned by the getter. Then that dict gets mutated.

Comment: @JoshuaMincer I edit my answer with examples answering your question.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I could be wrong, but it seems to me that not being able to access an attribute directly, `print(my_object.__a)` won't work, is closer to object oriented and how it's implemented in other language like Java.

Comment: Well, double underscore name-mangling isn't private. You *can* access the attribute directly. You just use `_MyClass__a`, nothing is stopping you. But even if it was private, that doesn't make it *more object oriented*. I wouldn't say Java is *more object oriented* than Python. Indeed, Java isn't even purely object oriented ,(everything is an object) and Python is (everything is an object)

Comment: I appreciate the extended solution in response. I'm now playing around with different strategies of returning-by-copy or using subclasses to redefine base-class methods. Thanks for the help!